# Hamcrest test that a map contains all entries from another map

Tags: java, hamcrest

I want to check that a map contains a certain set of entries.  It is allowed to contain other entries that are not in `expectedMap`.  I currently have the following assertion:

```
assertThat(expectedMap.entrySet(), everyItem(isIn(actualMap.entrySet())));
```

Although this does work, the failure message that it prints is confusing because the expected and received arguments have been reversed from normal usage.  Is there a better way to write it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`hasItems` does what you want, but in a non-obvious way. You have to jump through some hoops as Hamcrest has relatively limited support for matching `Iterable`s. (Without going into detail, this is due to the vagaries of how Java generics work- I'll post some more links with detail later).

(I'm assuming you're using generics, e.g. `Map<String, String>` as opposed to simply `Map`).

In the meantime you have a couple of options...

If you are happy with test code that raises warnings / using `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` in your test:

```
assertThat(actualMap.entrySet(), (Matcher)hasItems(expectedMap.entrySet().toArray()));
```

Explanation: there is no overload of `hasItems` that takes a `Set` or `Iterable`, but it will take an array. `Set.toArray()` returns `Object[]`, which won't match `assertThat` against your `actualMap.entrySet()` - but if you erase the declared type of the Matcher, it will happily proceed.

If you want an assertion that compiles without warnings, it gets uglier - you need to copy the `Set` into some kind of `Iterable<Object>` (you can't cast) in order to match on the Objects :

```
assertThat(new HashSet<Object>(actualMap.entrySet()), hasItems(expectedMap.entrySet().toArray()));
```

But to be perfectly honest, for clarity you are almost certainly best off asserting each entry individually:

```
for (Entry<String, String> entry : expectedMap.entrySet()) {
    assertThat(actualMap, hasEntry(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())); 
}
```

...or you could write your own Matcher - there are plenty of resources on how to do this online and on SO.

Comment: Yes, one reason I asked was because I wasn't happy with warnings or casts.  It's ugly.  I agree the last option is probably best for now. I have written a few matchers in the past and if I need to do this again I'll write one for it.